# Pandas quantile function not returning the correct number of given quantiles

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-interpolation

I have a dataframe with over 2,000 records that has multiple columns with various balances. Based on the balance amount I want to assign it to a bucket.

Trying to split each balance column into a quantile and have the following buckets `0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9`  Concretely, translating the balances into the following buckets: top 10%, top 20%, top 30%, etc...

If I'm understanding correctly, so long as there are more than 10 records it should bucket each record in a percentile based on linear interpolation.

So I run the following:

```
score_quantiles =  df.quantile(q=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9])
score_quantiles.to_dict()



# Arguments (x = value, p = field (i.e bal 1, bal2, bal3) , d = score_quantiles)

def dlpScore(x,p,d):
    if pd.isnull(x) == True:
        return 0 
    elif int(x) == 0:
        return 0
    elif x <= d[p][0.1]:
        return 1
    elif x <= d[p][0.2]:
        return 2
    elif x <= d[p][0.3]: 
        return 3
    elif x <= d[p][0.4]: 
        return 4
    elif x <= d[p][0.5]: 
        return 5
    elif x <= d[p][0.6]: 
        return 6
    elif x <= d[p][0.7]: 
        return 7
    elif x <= d[p][0.8]: 
        return 8
    elif x <= d[p][0.9]: 
        return 9
    else:
        return 10



df['SCORE_BAL1'] = df['bal1'].apply(dlpScore, args=('bal1',score_quantiles,))
```

Problem is, on some columns it gives me all the buckets, on others it only gives me a few:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to ensure it creates all the buckets? I'm probably missing something here.

Comment: What do you mean by "it should bucket each record in a percentile *based on linear interpolation*" and do you have a sample of your data?

Comment: Meaning if i have 10 distinct balances based on their value (low to high), each balance should be assigned a bucket, not just assigned to 3 buckets. Bal $0 will be bucket 1, balance $100 bucket 2, balance $500 bucket 3, etc...No sample of data since its company data.  Maybe I'm not understanding linear interpolation correctly with quantiles.

Comment: I think that you want the `qcut` function. See the [doc here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html). For instance if you want deciles you can just write `pd.qcut(df, q = 10)`.

Comment: @xicocaio i think youre right! thank you!!

Comment: If it works, please do inform me, so I can post an answer.

Comment: @xicocaio getting a lot of NaNs for no reason.  Trying to work it out

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible sample fololwing [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)? Also, here is an example I have used recently in my company `df['quantile'] = pd.qcut(df['target_column'], q=10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure that you are getting similar distributions among 'buckets' you might want to try the pandas `qcut` function. The [full documentation is here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html).

To use it in your code and get deciles for instance you could just do

```
n_buckets=10
df['quantile'] = pd.qcut(df['target_column'], q=n_buckets)
```

And if you want to apply a specific label you can just do something like this

```
n_buckets=10
df['quantile'] = pd.qcut(df['target_column'], q=n_buckets, labels=range(1,n_buckets+1))
```

**PS:** Just beware that for this latter case if `qcut` is not able to generate the desired number of quantiles (e.g., because there are not enough values to create a quantile), you will get an exception for passing more labels than there are quantiles.